# Why I cant access class attribute on native element using viewchild?

Tags: angular

I am trying to access `class` attribute of an element using `ViewChild` then is says `undefined` but I could access its other attributes like `style`,`click`.

-- * html * --

```
<button id="myButton" #myButton (click)="mybutton_submit()" class="foo" style="color:blue;text-align:center">My Button</button>
```

-- * ts * --

```
 @ViewChild('myButton') private myButton : ElementRef;
    console.log(`${this.myButton.nativeElement.class}`);  --> undefined
    console.log(`${this.myButton.nativeElement.style.color}`); --> blue
    this.myButton.nativeElement.click --> works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to get the list of class names.

```
    console.log(`${this.myButton.nativeElement.classList`);
```

Answer (score 2):

change class to className or classList as there is no class property on HTMLElement.